# list View click to set button to be visible

Tags: android, android-listview

I got these list view. I want to set this deleteRowButton to be visible when I tap on list row (I want that button to show up in the row that was tapped). So I gave that button android:visibility="invisible" attribute and added these two lines to onItemClick method:`

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        deleteRowButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listRowDeleteButton);
        deleteRowButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }
```

But when I tap on the some list row, that deleteRowButton shows up in row which is at the top of the list (not the one I tapped).
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding the TextView in the item you clicked:

```
deleteRowButton = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.listRowDeleteButton);
```

Comment: Now that button shows up at correct place but also show up when I scroll down one screen, on an item that wasn't pressed. How could I prevent this?

Comment: @Markonionini That's because ListView re-uses the views created. You'd need to save the item indexes which are not hidden and then apply accordingly in your `getView` method of the adapter. But that's a whole new question which has already been answered multiple times. If **this** question has been answered mark my answer as correct.